# What are the similarities between React and React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What are the similarities between these two? I know that they are made for different platforms React being for web and React Native being for mobile. But they are both made by Facebook to solve a similar problem. So, is there overlap? Are there similarities?

Comment: Of course there are similarities; you write your app in JS and run it. As is I believe the question is too broad (and likely OT since it's not an explicit programming question). You'd probably be better served by doing a little reading; it shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 5):

React for the web is actually using a library called ReactDOM. React itself is the underlying framework that is common across platforms for web (ReactDOM), native apps (React-Native), and VR (ReactVR).

The reason they abstracted React into its own layer is because they wanted to allow people to "Learn once, and build everywhere." However, the output for each is very different depending on the platform. For example, with React-Native, the output is actual native iOS (Objective-C) and Android (Java) code as opposed to ReactDOM which generates output similar to HTML and CSS.

As a rule of thumb, if you learn React, that will get you about 70-80% of the way there with all platforms since each has custom APIs you will interface with.

Comment: So are you telling me that if I write in React that code directly translate into React Native or what?

Comment: @Jeff Not quite. Each will require you to import specific libraries in order to transpile your React code into the appropriate platform. In addition, each platform does come with some specific APIs that are custom to each. For example, in ReactDOM, an input field is simply `<input type="text" />` while in React-Native, a text field is called <TextInput /> But overall the business logic and structure of the app will be pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

i believe they are both made by facebook.

> React gives you a template language and some function hooks to
>   essentially render HTML. That's all React outputs, HTML. Your bundles
>   of HTML / Javascript, called "components", are allowed things like
>   storing their own internal state in memory (such as which tab is
>   selected in a tab view), but in the end you just barf out HTML.

by [blog.andrewray.me](http://blog.andrewray.me/reactjs-for-stupid-people/)

and React-Native uses the same design as React, letting you compose a rich mobile UI from declarative components.

Comment: yes they are both made by facebook...